# Intersect keeping the count from both queries for ordering purpose

Tags: sqlite, intersect

I have two tables that I need to run query against each. The output of these two queries then need to be intersected and sorted based on the the number of occurrences of names found in both tables.

For example:

Query 1:

```
select * from userA
group by name
order by count(name) desc

---------------------------
ID  |  name  | count(name)
---------------------------
 1  |  John  |  2
 2  |  Mike  |  1
 3  |  Laura |  1
---------------------------
```

Query 2:

```
select * from userB
group by name
order by count(name) desc

---------------------------
ID  |  name  | count(name)
---------------------------
 3  |  Laura |  3
 1  |  John  |  1
 5  |  Peter |  1
---------------------------
```

Query 3:

```
select * from userA
group by name
order by count(name) desc
intersect
select * from userB
group by name
order by count(name) desc

---------------------------
ID  |  name   | count(name)
---------------------------
 1  |  John   |  1
 3  |  Laura  |  1
---------------------------
```

The problem is the intersect will re-run the count function discarding the count run from each query. What I'd like to see is the following output:

```
---------------------------
ID  |  name   | count(name)
---------------------------
 3  |  Laura  |  4
 1  |  John   |  3
---------------------------
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dataset is something like this:

**userA**

```
id          name      
----------  ----------
1           John      
1           John      
2           Mike      
3           Laura
```

**userB**

```
id          name      
----------  ----------
1           John      
3           Laura     
3           Laura     
3           Laura     
5           Peter
```

**You can write a query like so to get the desired result**

```
select id, name, count(*)
from (
    select id, name, 'A' as source from userA
    union all
    select id, name, 'B' from userB
) t
group by id, name
having count(distinct source) = 2;
```

**Result**

```
id          name        count(*)  
----------  ----------  ----------
1           John        3         
3           Laura       4
```

**Explanation**

Combine the dataset since you want to know the count of John and Laura from both tables, combined. `Union All` will allow keeping duplicates from both tables. When combining, remember the sources.

```
select id, name, 'A' as source from userA
union all
select id, name, 'B' from userB
```

The query above will combine data from both and give you this result:

```
id          name        source    
----------  ----------  ----------
1           John        A         
1           John        A         
2           Mike        A         
3           Laura       A         
1           John        B         
3           Laura       B         
3           Laura       B         
3           Laura       B         
5           Peter       B
```

Now, let's extract records that come from both tables only. So, we group by id and name and use the `having` clause to extract `count(distinct source) = 2`. That means, give me records that have 2 sources. Laura and John happen to been in both tables.

When selecting data, we ask for `count(*)` to get the number of records for id+name combination.

Comment: Thanks zedfoxus! I posted another question related to this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51645512/query-based-on-common-criteria-from-two-tables-and-sort-based-on-number-of-occur

Comment: @M.Ridha Can you please visit questions you have asked in the past and mark an answer as accepted, if the answer helped you? Let me know if you need help with marking an answer as accepted. Once you do that, let me know and I can take a look at your new question.

Comment: @M.Ridha not a problem. I'll highly recommend that you go back to other questions you have asked in the past and mark them all as answered, if the answers have helped you. It's a way to appreciate people who have taken the time to answer your questions. You can upvote them, optionally, if you liked the answer.